# .Net Core MVC form inside Foundation Modal without JQuery

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, zurb-foundation

I am using Foundation modal and placed a form inside. Now I am trying to add back end validation and I am pretty much confused on how to return the validation messages(and the modal open). The reason for using back end validation is because I want to see if the submitted value already exists in the database.

So my code for the view:

```
 <button class="button" data-open="categoryModal">Create A Group</button>

    <div class="reveal" id="categoryModal" data-reveal>
        <h1>Create Category</h1>
        @using (Html.BeginForm("CreateCategory", "Home"))
        {
           //razor inputs
        }
    </div>
```

and the code for the controller:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public IActionResult CreateCategory(CategoryVM category)
    {
        if(!ModelState.IsValid) return View(category);

        if (//category already exists)
        {
            ModelState.AddModelError("", "Category exists");
            return View(category);
        }
        _categoryRepository.Insert(new Category { Name = category.Name });
        return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
    }
```

To conclude: I want to return the view with the modal open and the validation messages as well.

Comment: Do a AJAX call to your backed and check weather category is already in DB. It is the best way to do this.

Comment: @AhamedIshak it seems that this is the only option. Thank you